# Copy , delete is not working to any external USB with Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hard-drive

as I am inserting any USB drive in my laptop , its shows me all the data in that drive but when i format that drive it don't erase its all data . I tried to copy paste some files in my external hard disk then in my laptop it shows it's done but when I re-plug my hard drive . Those files are not their i tried to copy it lot of time but shows same . Can anyone help me out to figure out the problem in this matter .when i am trying to copy files in any other small USB of 16gb or 8gb its copy 90% of the files and then show error occurred due to the large size of the file(4.2GB is the file size).

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1417791/edit) and add the following information: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: `lsb_release -a`, copy the output to post

Comment: If copying a 4.2 GB file is a problem, your drive is probably formatted as FAT32. That system cannot handle files bigger than 4 GB. Format it as EXT4 or NTFS will solve this problem. Also make sure that you unplug devices securely. If you don't do that not all files may be copied at the moment you unplug the device. The OS showing that all the files are copied, does not really say that they really are copied.,